# Including shared object in maven assembly

Tags: java, maven, shared-libraries

I'm currently trying to build my project with maven and sqlite4java. Which is available in the offical maven repositories.
The offical [sqlite4java page on google code](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/wiki/UsingWithMaven) does have an example configuration but it's a bit outdated and does not suit my needs. I want to have a single .jar-File in the end which i can deploy elsewhere. The problem here is the shared object depedency. I am using the official build goal from their page to copy the so to the build.dir/lib but my assembly goal crashes with:

```
[INFO] Failed to create assembly: Error adding file-set for 'com.almworks.sqlite4java:libsqlite4java-linux-i386:so:0.282' to archive: Error adding archived file-set. PlexusIoResourceCollection not found for: /home/lhw/.m2/repository/com/almworks/sqlite4java/libsqlite4java-linux-i386/0.282/libsqlite4java-linux-i386-0.282.so
No such archiver: 'so'.
```

​
What am I doing wrong? Here is my current pom.xml stripped from some dependencies unrelated to this topic

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>de.ring0.lhw</groupId>
  <artifactId>system</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
      <artifactId>sqlite4java</artifactId>
      <version>${sqlite4java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
      <artifactId>libsqlite4java-linux-i386</artifactId>
      <version>${sqlite4java.version}</version>
      <type>so</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <sqlite4java.version>0.282</sqlite4java.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>com.almworks.sqlite4java</groupId>
                  <artifactId>libsqlite4java-linux-i386</artifactId>
                  <version>${sqlite4java.version}</version>
                  <type>so</type>
                  <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
          <systemProperties>
            <property>
              <name>sqlite4java.library.path</name>
              <value>${project.build.directory}/lib</value>
            </property>
          </systemProperties>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <mainClass>de.ring0.lhw.Init</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
              <descriptorRefs>
                <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit :

I think that the jar-with-dependencies assembly descriptor tries to unpack the dependencies.

See the link :

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html

maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/… ...

```
<unpack>true</unpack>
```

And of course it fails to unpack the .so

So you might have to use a custom assembly to perform what you want to do

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 lhw lhw 716K Aug 30 12:23 .m2/repository/com/almworks/sqlite4java/libsqlite4java-linux-i386/0.282/libsqlite4java-linux-i386-0.282.so

Yes the file does exists and is copied to target/lib when the compile goal is executed.

Comment: How did you install/deploy the 'so' to the repo ?

mvn clean install:install-file ?

Do You have a pom for this installed dependency ? If Yes, did you set the type and packaging of the dependency to 'so' ? 

You can try to install it with 
mvn clean install:install-file -Dpackaging=so

Comment: libsqlite4java-linux-i386 Is the shared object dependency which is of type so as you can see abvoe. Its automatically downloaded to the local repository. sqlite4java is available in the standard maven repositories if you want to try it yourself.

Comment: I think that the jar-with-dependencies assembly descriptor tries to unpack the dependencies.

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html

...
<unpack>true</unpack>



So you might have to use a custom assembly to perform what you want to do.

Comment: That is what I expected. I hoped there would be a way without having to use custom assemblies. Well no helping it. Could you add your solution to the answer? So I can approve it for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create executable jar with stock "jar-with-dependencies" assembly descriptor and without using any startup shell/batch scripts. However, it requires dirty workarounds that doesn't involve much Maven configurations.

1. We need to place all native libraries [(included in sqlite4java zip download)](http://code.google.com/p/sqlite4java/downloads/list) to **src/main/resources** directory. Also remove sqlite4java native library dependency from your Maven POM file.
2. Because sqlite4java's native library loader doesn't look at your classpath or inside of JAR file, you have to **extract native libraries at startup**, and **set "sqlite4java.library.path" system property at runtime**. Please see the following sample code:

```
/** List of native libraries you put in src/main/resources */
public static final String[] NATIVE_LIB_FILENAMES = {
    "libsqlite4java-linux-amd64.so",
    "libsqlite4java-linux-i386.so",
    "libsqlite4java-osx.jnilib",
    "libsqlite4java-osx-10.4.jnilib",
    "libsqlite4java-osx-ppc.jnilib",
    "sqlite4java-win32-x64.dll",
    "sqlite4java-win32-x86.dll",
};

/**
 * Extract native libraries to the current directory.
 * This example needs Apache Commons IO (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)
 */
public static void extractNativeResources() {
    for(String filename: NATIVE_LIB_FILENAMES) {
        // Change "DemoSQLite2" to your class name
        final InputStream in = DemoSQLite2.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+filename);

        if(in != null) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Extracting " + filename);
                FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(in, new File(filename));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Can't extract " + filename);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Delete native libraries in the current directory
 */
public static void removeNativeResources() {
    for(String filename: NATIVE_LIB_FILENAMES) {
        File file = new File(filename);
        file.delete();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    boolean deleteNativesOnExit = false;    // Delete natives on exit

    // Extract native libraries if sqlite4java.library.path property is not set
    String sqlitePath = System.getProperty("sqlite4java.library.path");
    if(sqlitePath == null) {
        System.setProperty("sqlite4java.library.path", "."); // Read natives from current directory
        extractNativeResources();
        deleteNativesOnExit = true;
    }

    // Do SQLite jobs here
    final SQLiteConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(new File("test.db"));
    try {
        db.open();
        db.dispose();
        System.out.println("Success");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("FAILED");
    }

    // Delete the native libraries we extracted
    if(deleteNativesOnExit) removeNativeResources();
}
```

Now your app should be buildable with standard "jar-with-dependencies" descriptor, and your app is runnable with standard "java -jar your_jar.jar" command.

Of course, if sqlite4java gets updates in future, you have to manually update the native libraries in your resource directory.

If you have a better, less dirty solution, please let me know!

Comment: If you down vote it, please suggest me a better solution and/or what you think about it, so I can revise this post.

Comment: The problem with that approach is (I'm not downvoting) that it de-syncs your dependency - if whatever you need sqlite for changes it's version of that lib you'll need to catch that and update your copy. Be very careful before going down that route.